# RGB Color Image Histogram for Contrast Stretching using OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I write a program to make histogram for gray image using pixel data values. I used bellow code segment to increase contrast of the image accessing pixel values. How can i apply these logic to color image to increase contrast of the image.
gr is the gray image (convert from color image) and gr_im is new image.

```
int x = 0;
    for (int  i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) 
        {
            x = gr.at<uchar>(i,j);
            if (x < r1) 
            {
                gr_im.at<uchar>(i, j) = cvRound((s1/double(r1))*double(x));
            }
            else if(x <= r2){
                gr_im.at<uchar>(i, j) = cvRound((s2-s1 / double(r2-r1))*(x-r1) + s1);
            }
            else if (x > r2) {
                gr_im.at<uchar>(i, j) = cvRound((255-s2 / double(r1))*(x - r2) + s2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Convert the RGB image to gray segmented color space such as `LAB`, `YCrCb` or `HSV`, apply your contrast stretching algorithm to `L`, `Y` or `V` channel respectively and then again convert it to RGB.

Comment: Thank You. I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like code below:

```
cv::Mat hsv;
cv::cvtColor(image, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(hsv, channels)

// now call your function to specific channel

cv::merge(channels, hsv);
cv::cvtColor(hsv, image, CV_HSV2BGR);
```

Comment: This one is correct. But i need to do that process accessing each pixel values of the image. Thank You!